# Merge multiple rows together MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks more or less like this:

```
user  is_su  last_login  roles_for_groups
+------+---+------------+----------------------------+
| rob  | 1 | 2018-02-09 | admin, read                |
+------+---+------------+----------------------------+
| gian | 0 | 2018-06-21 | prod_full_access, readOnly | 
+------+---+------------+----------------------------+
| gian | 0 | 2018-06-21 | prod_full_access, CCT      |  
+------+---+------------+----------------------------+
| rob  | 1 | 2018-02-09 | admin, write               |  
+------+---+------------+----------------------------+
```

and I would like to merge into a single row all the rows with the same user, in a way such that the table will look like this:

```
+------+---+------------+---------------------------------+--+
| rob  | 1 | 2018-02-09 | admin, read, write              |  |
+------+---+------------+---------------------------------+--+
| gian | 0 | 2018-06-21 | prod_full_access, readOnly, CCT |  |
+------+---+------------+---------------------------------+--+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is an extremely bad idea to store the data comma separated, rather think about normalization

Answer (score 1):

Why not just query out the data the way you want, using `GROUP_CONCAT` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
    user,
    is_us,
    last_login,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT roles_for_groups) roles_for_groups
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    user,
    is_us,
    last_login;
```

It isn't clear whether the `is_us` and `last_login` columns are always functionally dependent on the `user`.  If not, then you should include some sample data which reveals this behavior.

Comment: is_us and last_login are always the same for each user

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.user,a.is_su,a.last_login,group_concat(distinct a.roles_for_groups separator ',' ) 
 from (select user,is_su,last_login,substring_index(roles_for_groups,',',1) as roles_for_groups from table union select user,is_su,last_login,substring_index(roles_for_groups,',',-1)  as roles_for_groups from table) a group by a.user
```

this query is only for roles_for_groups containing two values